# FFMPEG: Program does not quit when it returns an error (command line loops)

Tags: ffmpeg, video

I'm using ffmpeg to stream a video online, using the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i <stream_link> -t 00:09:00 video.mkv
```

This works well. But sometimes the stream ends, and then FFMPEG will throw a HTTP 403 error. However, it doesn't terminate the program and the error keeps looping.

```
"HTTP error 403 Forbidden"
"HTTP error 403 Forbidden"
"HTTP error 403 Forbidden"
"HTTP error 403 Forbidden"
"HTTP error 403 Forbidden"
```

Does anyone know if there is a way, such that rather than FFMPEG looping with the error message, that it insteads quits immediately? I have tried the following commands (-xerror and -err_detect -explode), but these don't seem to work:

```
ffmpeg -xerror -err_detect explode -i <stream_link> -t 00:09:00 video.mkv
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I found a workaround, which is to write a python script to run FFMPEG via the subprocess function, then stream through the output in real time and terminate the process once it identifies the line "HTTP error 403 Forbidden". Would be good to know if FFMPEG has something out of the box to terminate based on these types of errors.

Answer (score 0):

You could make ffmpeg to stop reading the stream if there are errors by using protocol-specific options to disable reconnects and persistent connections.

```
ffmpeg -help protocol=http
```